# How to run progress bar from 1 to 100 according to specific number of records

Tags: c#

i have a list in c# which holds some records. i am populating this list in a grid and while populating i am showing a progress bar on screen. now problem is that when number of records is in millions it took too much time to get populate in grid and meanwhile progress bar reaches to its max level i.e. 100% and stuck over there.
i want to run progress bar in such a way that it must be progressed same for any number of records. please help

i have try following  solution
 this.progressBar.Step = 3;
but it didn't worked

Comment: It's better if you add some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the number of records by 100. Whenever you processed so much records you increment progress by one.

Example: You have 1000 records. 1000/100 = 10. After 10 records you increment the progress-bar's Value property by one.

Use *double* as intermediate data type if you have a large number of records.

Adjust for rounding errors and off-by-one errors.

Decide if you increment "progress" at the start of your processing or after and of processing.

Comment: step property of progressbar is in integer format. if we assign a double value to it, it get assigned to 0.

Comment: That's why I wrote: double as intermediate type and. "Adjust for rounding errors"

Answer (score 0):

Divide the 100 by Number of records. this is your Step for progressBar,
if the number of records are 1000 then it will be 100/1000  = step